I get this package error : 'module 'texthero.preprocessing' has no attribute 'remove_stopwords'
I had trouble with my previous computer so I needed to switch and take another computer but with the new one, I got this error with this code. I don't understand why because on my previous computer it was working fine.
Here's my code :
from texthero import preprocessing

custom_pipeline = [preprocessing.fillna # Remplacez les valeurs non affectées par des espaces vides
                   , preprocessing.lowercase # transforme tout le texte en minuscules
                   , preprocessing.remove_digits # Supprimez tous les blocs de chiffres
                   , preprocessing.remove_punctuation # supprimez tous les string.punctuation (! "# $% & '() * +, -. / :; <=>? @ [\] ^ _` {|} ~)
                   , preprocessing.remove_diacritics # Supprimez tous les accents des chaînes
                   , preprocessing.remove_stopwords # Supprimez tous les mots vides
                   , preprocessing.remove_whitespace # Supprimez tout espace blanc entre les mots
                   , preprocessing.remove_html_tags # supprimer toutes les balises HTML d’une chaîne
                   , preprocessing.remove_brackets] # supprimer les crochets de la chaîne 
# custom_pipeline à l'argument pipeline
df_biens_cons_variable_pertinentes['clean_description'] = hero.clean(df_biens_cons_variable_pertinentes['description'], pipeline = custom_pipeline)
df_biens_cons_variable_pertinentes['clean_product_name'] = hero.clean(df_biens_cons_variable_pertinentes['product_name'], pipeline = custom_pipeline)

display(df_biens_cons_variable_pertinentes.head(2))

index = 1000

text=df_biens_cons_variable_pertinentes.description[index]
print('#text brut #:',text)
text_clean =df_biens_cons_variable_pertinentes['clean_description'][index]
print('#text_clean# :',text_clean)

And here's the error : AttributeError: module 'texthero.preprocessing' has no attribute 'remove_stopwords'
It also had an error for preprocessing.remove_html_tags
I searched on internet and it seems that no one encounter that kind of trouble with texthero so I'm kind of lost. Do you have any ideas why it is happening ?
I have also another question, why texthero doesn't appear in the tag section of stackoverflow ?

You said you just got a new computer. What version of the texthero package is installed?
